# Создание сайта для тестирования студентов в Django

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго дня! 
Я - начинающий "кодер", изучающий Django уровня "Крышка от чайника". Есть задача - создать сайт для тестирования студентов, чтобы можно было создавать тесты с вопросами и ответами и публиковать их на сайт, соответственно. Эдакий аналог Moodle. 
Измучился искать какое-либо решение или пути к решению. Наткнулся на [Django-survey](https://github.com/jessykate/django-survey), но полностью проблему решить не удалось.

Грубо говоря, нужно дать возможность админам создавать в админке (извините за тавтологию) категорию тестов и внутри их вопросы с ответами. Потом это все публикуется на отдельных страницах на главной, куда зарегистрированные студенты заходят и решают. Их решения должны сходиться с их id в БД и админ должен видеть соответственно результаты каждого студента (в той же админке).

Вопрос - **Как это все грамотно реализовать?** Будут полезны любые наводки, а за источники и иные ссылки, решающие проблему - отдельная благодарность!